# Why is Java8 flatmap returning a List of List?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I was trying to implement 'applying' a `List` of functions to a `List` of `File` objects using the following java 8 code.

```
List<Function<File, String>> mappingFunctions = Arrays.asList(
    (file) -> file.getName(),
    (file) -> file.getPath(),
    (file) -> ((Long) file.length()).toString(),
    (file) -> file.isDirectory() ? "Directory" : "File"
);

// collects all files in this and one level down directory
List<File> files =
    Stream.of(new File(".").listFiles())
          .flatMap(file -> file.listFiles() == null ? Stream.of(file) : Stream.of(file.listFiles()))
          .collect(toList());

System.out.println("All the files gathered ...\n");
files.forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println("\nApplying the list of functions to all the files gathered ...\n");
files.stream()
     .flatMap(file -> Stream.of(mappingFunctions.stream()
                                                .map((func) -> func.apply(file))
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output I get is as follows,

```
All the files gathered ...

.\.idea\compiler.xml
.\.idea\copyright
.\.idea\description.html
.\.idea\dictionaries
.\.idea\encodings.xml
.\.idea\misc.xml
.\.idea\modules.xml
.\.idea\project-template.xml
.\.idea\scopes
.\.idea\uiDesigner.xml
.\.idea\vcs.xml
.\.idea\workspace.xml
.\out\production
.\src\com
.\Test.iml
```

Applying the list of functions to all the files gathered ...

```
[compiler.xml, .\.idea\compiler.xml, 739, File]
[copyright, .\.idea\copyright, 0, Directory]
[description.html, .\.idea\description.html, 97, File]
[dictionaries, .\.idea\dictionaries, 0, Directory]
[encodings.xml, .\.idea\encodings.xml, 164, File]
[misc.xml, .\.idea\misc.xml, 525, File]
[modules.xml, .\.idea\modules.xml, 255, File]
[project-template.xml, .\.idea\project-template.xml, 91, File]
[scopes, .\.idea\scopes, 0, Directory]
[uiDesigner.xml, .\.idea\uiDesigner.xml, 8792, File]
[vcs.xml, .\.idea\vcs.xml, 164, File]
[workspace.xml, .\.idea\workspace.xml, 28470, File]
[production, .\out\production, 0, Directory]
[com, .\src\com, 0, Directory]
[Test.iml, .\Test.iml, 437, File]
```

Question 1: Why do I get a list of list in second output whereas only a single list in the first ? Both of the them use flatmap over a stream of collection.

Question 2: Is there a better way to achieve the same in Java 8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case the `flatMap` method produced a `Stream<List<String>>` whose single element is a `List<String>`.

In the first case the `flatMap` method either produces a `Stream<File>` of a single `File` or a `Stream<File>` of an array of `File`s.

Note that there are two `Stream.of` methods :

One accepts an array of type T (or a variable number of T arguments) and produces a Stream of T:

```
of(T... values)
```

This method is used when you write:

```
.flatMap(file -> Stream.of(file.listFiles()))
```

The other accepts a single T and produces a Stream with a single element T:

```
of(T t)
```

This method is used when you write:

```
.flatMap(file -> Stream.of(.. some expression that produces a List ..))
```

If you want your final Stream processing to produce a single Stream of Strings :

```
files.stream()
        .flatMap(file ->  mappingFunctions.stream()
                                          .map((func) -> func.apply(file)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This way, the lambda expression inside `flatMap` would produce a `Stream<String>` and `flatMap` would flatten those `Stream`s into a single `Stream<String>`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking to understand. How in the second case the element got converted to a list of Strings. I was expecting a single list of strings, whereas I got a list of list of strings. Is there a detailed explanation I can find somewhere ?

Comment: @MadhurBansal You can remove the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and the `Stream.of (..)`, and the flatMap would return a `Stream<String>` instead of a `Stream<List>`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @MadhurBansal see my edit. The explanation is that Stream.of(List<String>) produces a `Stream<List<String>>` with a single element, and not a `Stream<String>` as you expected.

Comment: Oh ok, got it now - many thanks Eran. The list argument was not recognized by Stream.of as a vararg !! The solution you proposed works.